# Does GraphQL generate actual SQL queries?

Tags: sql, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and can't seem to understand how GraphQL is able to integrate with relational databases. Does it convert a GraphQL query and generate the actual SQL query (with the proper joins) which is used for getting the data from the database?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is (similar to SQL) just a standard that defines the structure and behaviour of queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL is a format for querying any type of data, but relational databases are where most data in the world lives, so there is software such as Apollo Server that implements reads and writes to databases, and naturally they would use SQL since that's how they work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Apollo Server! That's the missing link.